# Use an image from isolated storage as the icon in Xamarin on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

**Context:** We are using Xamarin forms to develop for iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.1. One of the desired aspects of our application was to use [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) as the main text font and for icons etc (as we already use extensively in our web app).

In our app we are using the [ToolbarItem](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem/) class to generate a platform independent menu. Unlike the other platforms, on Windows Phone there is an Icon. We have constructed a `FontAwesomeRenderer` class that takes Font Awesome lookup codes (e.g. fa-plus) and generates an image that is stored in the apps isolated storage and an associated [ImageSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/) created for it (Note: This image displays correctly). However whenever we create a [FileImageSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource/) nothing is shown.

Could a custom renderer for the toolbar be used on Windows Phone?

Could the ImageSource somehow be converted to a FileImageSource?

**Question** How can an image (already stored in the isolated storage) be used as the icon for a ToolbarItem and work on the Windows Phone?

Comment: have you tried something like this on you platform-specific code? https://spasol.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/creating-custom-live-tiles-for-windows-phone/

Comment: In the end, it was easier to build a custom utility to generate all the icons we will need in the toolbar because the icons in the toolbar will never change.